# what does this sentence mean or is it capable of more than one interpretation?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I welcome all the delegates on behalf of ABC corporation. 
In this sentence, the phrase "on behalf of" makes the sentence quite ambiguous. My question is whether "I" refers to a delegate of ABC corporation or the "delegates" are from the ABC corporation.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not ambiguous although it's not clear where the delegates are from or who they represent.

They may or may not be from ABC corporation; it's possible, although it seems unlikely, that a single corporation might send many delegates to a conference.

The speaker is a representative of ABC corporation and he/she welcomes the delegates (to one or other conference) in the name of the corporation.

Exactly what position the speaker holds is not specified. He/she may or may not be a delegate.